# Compile a 32-bit libfuzzer application on the 64-bit linux

Tags: clang, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, llvm-clang

Recently, I've been familiar with libfuzzer and want to give it a go. Well, as far you know for using Sanitizer it's better to compile the binary in 32bit mode because it on 64bit system requests a lot of memory.
So, when I'm trying to compile my fuzzer in 32bit mode (-m32) with clang-6.0, I get the following error :

```
CC="clang-6.0 -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -fsanitize=address,fuzzer  -fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard,trace-cmp,trace-gep,trace-div -m32 " 
...............................

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have `libstdc++.so` 32bit version then I use this command to make the compile easier:

```
cp /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so{.6,}
```

But after that the error message is changed to this :

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerClangCounters.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerCrossOver.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerDriver.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerExtFunctionsDlsym.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerExtFunctionsDlsymWin.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerExtFunctionsWeak.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerExtFunctionsWeakAlias.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.fuzzer-i386.a(FuzzerExtraCounters.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
..............
..............
..............
```

Do you have any idea what the root cause of the problem is and how I can solve it?